# form input submit to database using $wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering how to insert form input value to wordpress database.
In a wordpress theme, I want to add an input element and insert it to database.
Clicking the submit button, I think there is no effect to insert for the following codes.

## wordpress_theme_file.php

```
<form id=”form_reply” action=”database.php” method=”post”>
…
<input type=”text” id=”newValue” name=”newValue” />
…
</form>
```

## database.php

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$inputValue = $_POST[‘ newValue ‘];
$wpdb->insert(‘wp_table_name’, ‘field_name’=>$inputValue);  // wp_table_name and field_name in database
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert to wordpress table like this

```
global $wpdb;
$inputValue = $_POST['newValue'];
$wpdb->insert( 
    'table_name', 
    array( 
        'column1' => $inputValue
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s' // if the field type is string
    ) 
);
```

[for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code which help you to insert data to database in wordpress :

```
 <?php
     global $wpdb

    $address = 'address';
    $firstn = "First Name';
    $wpdb->insert( 'users', array( 'address' => $address, 'first_name' => $firstn ), array( '%s', '%s' ) )

 ?>
```

In above "users" is table name and Fields are : address and first name.

Reference :  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows